# Install facebook connect plugin in PhoneGap app

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a `PhoneGap` app and I'm trying to install the `Facebook connect plugin` so I can have a Facebook login button on it but I didn't manage to do it.

I looked [here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-integrate-facebook-login-into-a-cordova-based-app/) and in a lot of other websites for days.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

use this

https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB

it is easy to setup and setup guide is pretty straight forward and simple.

here is full detailed tutorial

http://kmturley.blogspot.in/2014/10/facebook-login-inside-hybrid-app-using.html

basic syntax is

```
openFB.login(callback, {scope: 'email,publish_actions'});
```